# How to autostart a background program by a non-root user?

Tags: cron, non-root-user, services

As a non-root user, I want to run a background job when the system boots. It's sort of a service which doesn't require root privilege. Is there a way to do it?

One way is to put `sudo -u user command` in `rc.local`, but editing `rc.local` requires root privilege.

Another way is to launch it from `cron` every minute and check for any running instance, but firstly it wakes up the system unnecessarily and secondly, there can be race condition in checking running instances.

A third way is to run it in `~/.bash_profile`, but I want to start it without user login.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use cron if your version has the `@reboot` feature. From [man
5 crontab](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=crontab&apropos=0&sektion=5&manpath=Debian+unstable+sid&format=html&locale=en):

> Instead of the first five fields, one  of  eight  special  strings  may appear:
>
> ```
>   string         meaning
>   ------         -------
>   @reboot        Run once, at startup.
>   …
> ```

You can edit a user-local crontab with the command `crontab -e` without root privileges. Then add the
following line:

```
@reboot /usr/local/bin/some-command
```

Now your command will be run once at boot time.

Comment: Is it unusual for `crontab -e` to create the cron file under `/tmp`?

Comment: @Elliott That depends on your editor. In the end the file will end up in `/var/spool/cron/crontabs`.