# possibility of running daemons with under privileged users during bootup

Tags: linux, init-script, privileges, setcap

I have an authoritative DNS daemon in my test DNS setup which is responsible to provide host IP at best choice.

This daemon/process can run by setting some capabilities using `setcap` and then a development user can start or stop this without becoming the root user or using `sudo`.

But while booting up the box, this daemon/process again appears as running as root in `ps` output.

Can I start/stop this process with minimal capability/privileges from a non-root user? Then, at the bootup, I also don't want to see this running as the root user.

Is there any mechanism in init scripts to run the given process with non zero uid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `su` in your startup scripts:

```
su -s /bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/somedaemon' someuser
```

Another solution would be to start the daemon [using cron](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/85681/12779).

Answer (score 2):

You should just call:

```
sudo -u username your_daemon_name
```

in the init script, as `root` runs the init script it will not ask for a password but run the scripts as username.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [systemd](http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/) (as of today, only Slackware, Ubuntu and Debian among Linux distributions are using anything else) you can set the user/group in its .service file (see systemd.service(5), systemd.exec(5), and browse through the copious documentation [here](http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/)).

Comment: Ubuntu and Debian are both using systemd now. I think Slackware is the only major distro left to not use systemd (at least judging from the list of most popular distros at distrowatch).